# Interpreting the results of RSM Analyses from Minitab

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design, minitab, response-surface-methodology

I am working on a small project to optimize the performance of an iron electrocoagulation reactor for water treatment.

My professor wanted me to build a model to predict turbidity removal based on variations in 3 input factors (Charge dosage, Charge Dosage Rate, and Conductivity of water). After some literature review, I thought RSM could accomplish this goal. I am new to the topic and my professor had no idea about this particular methodology.

So, I spent some time reading textbooks and articles and eventually designed an experimental plan (CCD). I ran 20 experiments with 5 levels of input factors.
[image]

After I completed the experiments, I have been struggling with interpreting the results ***and*** I am unsure if I applied my readings from various textbooks and articles correctly.

For example, with the above input parameters, I get a F value of 1.9 for the full quadratic model and my graphs look like this:
[image]

But if I just do some calculations and change the input factors to Current, Time of Reaction, Conductivity the F value of the full quadratic model from ANOVA is 4.94. My graph changes to something like this:
[image]

I also tried with making more calculations, changing the input factors, and the highest model F-value I got so far was 9.81.

I don't get how to interpret these changing F-values and other results that are generated by Minitab. I am also confused - is my model even capable of making predictions with such a low F-value? I cannot figure out how to use these results to decide what set of experiments I must conduct next to make progress on my project.

If someone can point me to any resources to interpret all the results generated by Minitab or in general on how to proceed with RSM results, it would be incredibly helpful. Thank you soooo much!!

Comment: The full quadratic models is using most of the available degrees of freedom thus leaving little information to evaluate the error term.  From the information provide you do have enough information for the prediction.  Use the generated model to predict the optimal values (near the high side of dose, dosage rate and conductivity) and run that experiment.  The model can also indicate that the optimal is insensitive to small changes in the input value, i.e. a hill and not a mountain.